# Is it possible to change text quality on transparent image with PHP Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have jpeg background and want to place a text on this background. But my text is very sharp comparing to background. I tried to convert text layer to jpeg and compress and use `compositeImage` after. It works fine, but when I converting text to jpeg, I'm loosing transparency and text have white background. Any suggestions how to fix it?

Example:

[image]

Background is a compressed jpeg with usual pixelization. I'm writing text on background with

```
$im = new Imagick('template.png');

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$im->annotateImage($draw, $x, $y, 0, $text);
```

but text looks unnatural sharp on compressed image and I want to compress the text (but not the background). If I compress the final image (with text and background) final quality of background getting worse. Can I compress text layer only with `setImageCompressionQuality` without converting it to jpeg (because if I convert text layer to jpeg I will loose transparency?

Comment: Really can't suggest anything without seeing the code, and/or example images.

Comment: @emcconville Example is simple - I want to change `setImageCompressionQuality` of `annotateImage` object and keep transparency for `annotateImage`

Comment: If you want someone to help you, it's generally a good idea to make it easy for them. Please provide sample images and code, and show what happens as well as what you would prefer to happen. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, question updated

Comment: Maybe create your text around half the size you want it and then resize it up to take the edge off its quality?

Comment: JPG does not support transparency. Best to work with PNG or TIF as intermediate format, then save the result as JPG